# Area of the field as function of $r$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why answer to the below question results in negative area? Area should not be negative. Why area when expressed as function of $r$ is negative?

[image: My question]

Comment: I found $A=2lr+\pi r^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Ahhh ... this was a tricky one. You have to pay attention to the fact that the perimeter is $1$ mile. Expressing the perimeter as $2\pi r + 2l=1$, and solving for $l$ in terms of $r$, you get $l=\frac12-\pi r$. Then you can plug it back into $A = 2rl +\pi r^2$ to get $r-2\pi r^2+\pi r^2 = r - \pi r^2$, and since $r$ must be $< \frac1{2\pi}$, you end up with a positive area in the end.

Comment: But why r must be <1/(2π)? I don't understand how you got that result. If I replace r with 1 or 2 in the resulting equation I get negative value.